# Highlight the textcolor in android html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html, textview

I have to develop one android application.

I have to display the textview using html.fromHtml .

Here this is my content:

```
**Hottie Mallika Sherawat speaks about the men whom she’s over the moon about**
```

In these text ,have aligned on html file like below:

```
   <span style="color:#ff8c00;">Mallika Sherawat&nbsp;</span>
```

I have to highlight the that color on  Mallika Sherawat text only on my android textview also.

How can i do ???

I have wrote below code:

```
String fullcontent = in.getStringExtra("FullContent");
    full_content = fullcontent.substring(1);

    lblContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);

  lblContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(full_content),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Here the html.fromHtml is supported b,p,italic text..But why it is not supported for highlight the particular text ???   pls how can i do ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of html tags supported by textview

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

For using SpannableString

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Example:

Using Spannable String

```
    _tv.setText("");
              SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);
        ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 23, 0);
        ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 23, 0);
        ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 23, 0); 
     _tv.setText(ss1);
```

[image]

Using Html

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>hello</font> <font color=#ffcc00>world</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Hi span is supporting  or not suppoting in android html.fromHtml method....my html content style is span..this is my backend process....thats why asking

Comment: use spannable string seperately. check the example in the link. it works

Comment: yes...the html content am getting from xml feed....then how can i do separately...this is dynamic string....any solution for dynamic string ????

Comment: first check the list of html tags supported. check the first link in the answer. If the tags do not help. Extract text from the html tags using JSOUP http://jsoup.org/download. Then use the spannable string on the extracted string. I don't think span tag is supported. You can try to use webview to display text

Comment: ya i saw that...using jsoup means the html tags all are removed and added all content only....it is not support b,italic,etc

Comment: jsoup is for extracting text. Once you extract text you need to style your text displayed in textview using the spannable string

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Hi span is supporting or not suppoting in android html.fromHtml method....my html content style is span..this is my backend process....thats why asking